# Update WinRM on Win2008R2 to manage it with Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, winrm

I want to manage Win2008R2  with Windows Server 2012.
What i've done:

1. install .Net Framwork 4.0 on Win2008R2 server
2. install WMF 3.0
3. install hotfix KB2682011

powershell> winrm quickconfig

and got:

```
WSManFault
Message
    ProviderFault
        WSManFault
            Message = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
```

Error number:  -2147024894 0x80070002

How can i fix it?

Comment: winrm /qc is deprecated. Can you try Enable-PSRemoting instead?

Comment: Oh and also make sure that you're executing it from the PS 3 engine, not PS 2.